# Complex business logic in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, java-ee-6

The question: from a programming point of view, does WordPress allow a similar kind of flexibility that I would get by writing my own Java EE system? E.g. if the site owners suddenly decided that users whose birthday was on a Wednesday had to be sent a notification email and their birthday event had to be entered into a calendar that other members of the site could then RSVP to and then give a star rating afterwards to say how much they enjoyed it... could I do that easily with WP?

Hope that's clear, really welcome any feedback.

Comment: `I bet this question gets closed in less than 15 seconds` If you know this is a bad question, why did you ask it?

Comment: its not a bad question though is it? read it. Read to the end.

Comment: its bad based on that first sentence alone, and the `(Please don't close this question mods - I know you want to...!)`

Comment: I won't judge the question as "bad" or "good", but I will say it is not a good fit for SO - which was clearly known at time of posting.

Comment: It's a programming question about the ability of WordPress vs an enterprise framework

Comment: No it's a shopping question. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: @Richard "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. ***Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site*** and push other questions off the front page." - The problem is there is no "absolute" correct answer, no reference, no algorithm to answer this. While I *could* give numerous experience/anecdotal answers, this would need to be a much more *refined* question for me to feel it had merit on SO.

Comment: Well the question is ultimately, can I achieve the what's in the last paragraph using WordPress?

Comment: @Richard Then fix/update the title and post: ask the *actual* task/question and remove everything else.

Comment: Is that OK? Have updated the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress is a bit easier to get started out with, and you can install whatever plugins you want easily. The only problem with it, is that it is a lot like windows: it accounts for many people's use cases.

For you, with a business/corporate (you mentioned corperate applications before the edit of your question)/extensible platform in mind, I would recommend sticking with what you've got. You've written it yourself (or as a team) so you know everything about it, and what to look for when there is a bug. It's easily extended with your own code, and you don't have to sort through and learn a new language.

Wordpress is great for blogs, as that is what it is designed for. It is good for general purpose websites with dynamic layouts, but relatively static content (blog posts, write it once, edit a few times, but relatively static). Sure, you could write plugins for it, and many have been written, But it won't have nearly the capabilities you seem to require without major extensions.

Also, being written in PHP, it has to be interpreted, as opposed to java, which is a semi-compiled/optimized bytecode (a bit complex) but java runs faster than the equivalent PHP code.

So benefits of your system:

- Faster
- More reliable
- Suited for very dynamic content

Benefits of wordpress:

- Easier to extend
- Suited for static content
- Easier for novices to use (but your own interface may work just fine)

Comment: Excellent answer Tyzoid, thanks for replying. I'll definately check out WP to see what it can do. Very limited for time hence getting opinions from SO users is really appreciated before I go off checking 'yet another technology'. Even if I don't use it for this project (which I prob wont based on feedback) I may use it for some things in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is incredibly flexible, and can, without a doubt, be a viable framework for your app.  You should definitely check out it.

That said, if you're building something this complicated, I'd go with what you know.  You're gonna make mistakes and do things in weird ways on your first few WP projects.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll check it out. I appreciate your feedback.